A counterexample that $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is not complete.
Can anyone give an example which can directly indicate that the following norm space is not complete:
$$
C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) = \{f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n): f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n), |\nabla f| \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\}, 
$$
with the norm
$\|f\|_{L^p} + \|\nabla f\|_{L^p}$.
We all know that $\overline{C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)} = W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Therefore, pick a
function $g \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) \setminus C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. (I think this will not be hard.) Then there exists a sequence $f_n \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ converges to $f$, which means that $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is not a complete space.
However, can anyone give an explicit example of $C^\infty$ functions, which form a Cauchy sequence, but converge to a function which does not belong to $C^\infty$?

You’re considering the completeness of $C^\infty (\mathbb{R}^n)$ relative to the norm you provided, right?

For an example with $n=1, p=2$. Pick your favourite cut-off function, i.e. $\chi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\chi(x)=1$ for $\vert x \vert \leq 1$ and $\chi(x)=0$ for $\vert x \vert\geq 2$. Then define the sequence of functions $$ f_n(x) = \chi(x) \sqrt{x^2+1/n}.$$ This converges in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ to $\vert x \vert \chi(x)$ which is not smooth (not even differentiable at the origin). This can easily be generalized to any $n$. One would need to do the computation to see whether this works also for other $p$.

Alternatively, you could consider $$ f_n(x) = (\Vert x \Vert^2+1/n)^{1-\delta} e^{-\Vert x \Vert^2} $$ for some small $\delta>0$ depending on $p$ and $d$. Then you can try to show that $\Vert f_n \Vert_{W^{1,p}}\leq C<\infty$ uniformly in $n$ for $\delta$ small enough and $f_n(x)\rightarrow \Vert x\Vert^{2(1-\delta)} e^{-\Vert x\Vert^2}$ pointwise (and same for the gradients), which by dominated convergence would imply your statement (as $f_n\in C^\infty$, in fact it is even real-analytic).

Or even easier, you can consider $$ f_n(x) = (\Vert x \Vert^2+1/n)^{4/3} e^{-\Vert x \Vert^2} $$ and $$ f(x) = \Vert x \Vert^{8/3} e^{-\Vert x \Vert^2}. $$ Then we do not need to worry about infinities and no parameters need to be chosen.

Consider
$$ f_n(x) = (\Vert x \Vert^2+\frac{1}{n})^{4/3} e^{-\Vert x \Vert^2}$$
and
$$ f(x) = \Vert x \Vert^{8/3} e^{-\Vert x \Vert^2}. $$
Those functions are all in $C^1(\mathbb{R}^d)\cap L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (the exponential decay kills the power law growth of the first factor). Their partial derivatives are given by
$$ \partial_j f_n(x) = \left(\frac{4}{3}(\Vert x\Vert^2+\frac{1}{n})^{1/3}2x_j -2x_j\right) e^{-\Vert x \Vert^2} $$
and
$$ \partial_jf(x) = \left(\frac{4}{3} (\Vert x \Vert^2)^{1/3}2x_j-2x_j\right) e^{-\Vert x \Vert^2}. $$
One readily checks that
$$ \vert f_n(x)\vert,  \vert f(x) \vert \leq  (\Vert x \Vert^{2}+1)^{4/3} e^{-\Vert x \Vert^2} $$
and
$$\vert \partial_j f_n(x) \vert,\vert \partial_j f(x) \vert \leq \frac{8}{3} (\Vert x \Vert^{5/3}+1) e^{-\Vert x \Vert^2} $$
and the upper bounds are both in all $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (with $p<\infty$).
Furthermore,  we also have for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$
$$ f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x), \partial_j f_n(x) \rightarrow \partial_j f(x). $$
Thus, by dominated convergence, we get that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. However, $f$ is not smooth (it is $C^2$, but not $C^3$), while $f_n$ is smooth (even real-analytic).
Added: Increasing the fractional power of the first prefactor (yet not making it an integer), we get counterexamples for real-analytic functions in $W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ which converge in $W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to a non-smooth function.
